# Dynamic select with a plus button

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I am trying to do a select fields that update dynamically. I have made it work, but my page has a 'plus' button that will add other `select` fields when clicked

How do I make this `select` field added by the plus button update itself too?

This is my code for the dynamic `select`, and for the plus button. I tried dynamically selecting again after I click the plus button but no luck, maybe my code itself is wrong

```js
$(document).ready(function($) { //dinamic select
  $('#subsidiary_add').change(function() {
    $.get("{{ url('compras/ordem_compra/retorna_pedido')}}", {
        id_subsidiary: $(this).val()
      },
      function(data) {
        var model = $('#id_pedido_compra_add');
        model.empty();
        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
          model.append("<option value='" + key + "'>" + value + "</option>");
        });
      }
    );
  });
});

var counter = 0;
$('.modal-body').on('click', '#add', function() { // "plus button"
  $('#plusbutton').append(
    "<label for='id_pedido_compra' class='col-md-2 col-form-label added'>Descrição</label>" +
    "<div class='form-group col-md-4 added'>" +
    "<select class='form-control' name='id_pedido_compra" + counter + "' id='teste'>" +
    "<option selected='selected' value>...</option>" +
    "</select>" +
    "</div>" +
    "<label for='quantidade_comprada' class='col-md-2 col-form-label added'>Quantidade</label>" +
    "<div class='form-group col-md-4 added'>" +
    "<input id='quantidade_comprada' class='form-control' name='quantidade_comprada" + counter + "' type='text'>" +
    "</div>"
  );
  counter++;
});
```

Comment: i remember in laracasts forum someone posted the code, may be match your request http://os33.atwebpages.com/dynamic_form_input.html

Comment: Make `name='id_pedido_compra" + counter + "'` an array instead eg: `name='id_pedido_compra[]'` then simply traverse the dom to populate the options.. one of the first things you should learn is that dom ids need to be unique else jquery will select the first it finds.